# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in StudentsController#destroy Could not find table 'students_subjects'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have following two controller

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :semesters
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

And my database tables are

```
class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :subjects
  end
end

class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :dept

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :students
  end
end
```

My edit, show, create of subject and student work just fine. But when I try to delete any subject or student I get the following error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SubjectsController#destroy
>
> Could not find table 'students_subjects'

It seems there should be another table named 'students_subjects' for many to many association. How do I do that? Using scaffold or something? I just started to learn rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is saying that you are missing the join table in the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.  Your `edit`, `show`, `create` of `student` and `subject` should only work separately.  There are no associated records created in the database because the join table is missing.

Create a migration to add the join table.  Note that you wouldn't need a model for this join table.

```
class CreateStudentsSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :students_subjects, id: false do |t|
      t.references :student, null: false
      t.references :subject, null: false
    end

    # Add an unique index for better join speed!
    add_index(:students_subjects, [:student_id, :subject_id], :unique => true)
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :students_subjects
  end
end
```

**Update:**

> How to create a migration?

Issue the following command from your rails application root directory:

```
rails g migration create_students_subjects
```

Then replace the content of the generated migration file in `db/migrate/` directory with the class definition above.  Then after execute `rake db:migrate`.

Note that I had missed `id: false` in the `create_table` method above to tell Rails not to create a primary key for this table.  I've added this option with this update.

Comment: how do i create the migration? I did it but no tables added in the database after db:migrate

Comment: @user1478137, please see my update on how to create a migration.